# Search by meta string in select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I'm trying to allow users to search one of my dropdown boxes.

For each option in the dropdown, I want to include a title and some meta keywords to search by.

Here is my code:

```
<select id="part_selection" name="part_selection" multiple>
    <repeat group="{{ @parts }}" value="{{ @part }}">
        <option value="{{ @part['uid'] }}">{{ @part['title'] }}</option>
    </repeat>
</select>
```

My code above does not include the keywords for the options, because I've been unable to get it to work.

My first thought was to add a `<span>` inside the option text, with a hidden style so it would not show but would be searchable.

```
<option value="{{ @part['uid'] }}">{{ @part['title'] }} <span style="display: none;">{{ @part['attributes'] }}</span></option>
```

But this did not work, because option tags cannot contain other tags.

So I searched around for a solution, and came across [this rather cryptic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19465499/5827005), which simply states "Use Select2". I've had Select2 installed in my server already, and didn't know it had this feature, so I initialized my select element using Select2.

```
$('#part_selection').select2({dropdownParent: $('#part_selection').parent(), width: '100%'});
```

That said, I'm not able to find any indication in the documentation that this is capable of searching hidden option text, and I can't seem to figure it out myself either.

What I've tried:

```
//Add data-meta tag to element, saw this somewhere...
<option value="{{ @part['uid'] }}" data-meta"{{ @part['attributes'] }}">{{ @part['title'] }}</option>
```

Other than this, I'm at a complete loss as for what to try, and I'm having a really hard time finding anything related to this by Googling.

How can I search hidden meta/description information in a select box?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by overwriting the `matcher` function in select2.

This code will allow the search box in select2 to search the `data-meta` attribute on any option.

```
$(selector).select2({matcher: function(params, data) {
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return data;
    }
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
        return null;
    }

    var search_term = params.term.toLowerCase();
    var text_value = data.text.toLowerCase();

    //in my case, the data-meta attribute is a json object.
    //if you just want to use text here, you could do:
    //var meta = $(data.element).data('meta').toLowerCase();
    var meta = JSON.stringify($(data.element).data("meta")).toLowerCase();

    if (text_value.indexOf(search_term) > -1 || meta.indexOf(search_term) > -1) {
        var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
        return modifiedData;
    }

    return null;            
    }
});
```