# show and hide span in <option> in Angular7

Tags: html, css, angular, angular7

I got stuck in one issue where I need to show/hide span inside the **option** of **select**.

When user hovers over the options then I need to show the amount,if user checked one of the option then I need to hide the amount.

Don't want to use Jquery,use simple native javascript here.

Here is my demo  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auirs1

Applied css to show and hide the span,but its not working

Comment: A span inside of a select is not semantically correct html.

Comment: You are not closing your option tag

Comment: You can't use html inside <option> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option "Permitted content Text with eventually escaped characters (like &eacute;)."

Comment: Pls check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465459/hide-the-text-inside-select-control

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use ngModel on select and check its selected value on your span like below:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="select">
        <option *ngFor="let bank of banks">
          {{ bank }}
        <span *ngIf="!select" class="only-show-on-hover">1000$</span>
</select>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: about about in hover?